# avoid underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph because of linebreak

Tags: tables, line-breaking, warnings

It seems to be a common question, but the other werent adressing my code.

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\small
\caption{Absolute and relative frequencies } 
\label{FreqFair}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
\scalebox{1}{
\begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.15\textwidth}p{0.15\textwidth}p{0.15\textwidth}p{0.15\textwidth}p{0.1\textwidth}} \\ \toprule%{L C R} 
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{Stated importance} \\ 
&Very\linebreak important&Important&Moderately\linebreak important&Not\linebreak     important&Total \\ \midrule
\end{tabular}
}
\normalsize
\end{table}
```

I guess using the line break in the first row is not the best idea, but then it looks exactly how I want it.

Comment: Hi, I think your question is the same one as [Tabular: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60672/tabular-underfull-hbox-badness-10000-in-paragraph-at-lines?rq=1). Please have a look whether it helps. If it helps, let us now and we will mark the questions as duplicates. If it doesn't help, please edit your question and indicate what problems exactly do you have.

Comment: Please construct a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) from `\documentclass...` until `\end{document}`.

Comment: That one help cause I used
     \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}} as they suggested. I dont really get why, but I think you can just close it, thx for the help

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, the problem here is using `\linebreak` instead of `\newline` for a manual break, the other question is about setting \raggedright and automatic line breaks.

Comment: Ok but then again it seems to be answered. I used the newly defined column and keppt the \linebreak and the error was gone.

Answer (score 5):

If you replace the `\linebreak` macro calls with `\newline`-s, the bad boxes will go away. That's because the `\linebreak` command causes LaTeX to stretch the line so it extends to the right margin. And this can't be done by stretching the whitespaces only if you have one word...

Changing the alignment in the cells (eg. to `\raggedright`) could also remove the bad boxes.

(Thanks to @DavidCarlisle for pointing out how wrong I was.)

Comment: er no:-) `\\ ` will end the table row. Right idea though, but you want `\newline` . Also  `flushleft` is an environment, `\raggedright` is the command form.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle errrrh errrrhhhh Aye Captain...:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle fixed, thank you, and sorry for the bad reading